# How exactly is Skorohod's Representation Theorem applied here?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I have a question about applying the Skorohod Representation Theorem. Let $(R^{N+1}_+,\mathcal{F},Q)=:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},Q)$ be a probability space, $\{X_k:0\le k \le N\}$ be the canonical stochastic process, i.e. $X_k:\mathbb{R}^{N+1}_+\to\mathbb{R}$, $X_k((x_0,\dots,x_N))=x_k$ and $\mathcal{F}_k$ the filtration generated by $X_k$. Moreover we have a subset $F_n\subset \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\lim_n F_n = \mathbb{R}_+$. Assume we have a continuous real-valued function $g:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$ with $|g(x)|\le C(1+x^p)$ for $p>2$ and a constant $C$. Define $f_n:=g|_{F_n}$ to be the restriction of $g$ to $F_n$. The $f_n$ has the property that $\sup_{x\in F_n}\frac{|f_n(x)|}{(1+x^p)}\le n$ (maybe this is not needed). Since $g$ is continuous we have that for $x_n\ge 0$, $x\ge 0$ with $x_n\to x$ then $g(x)=\lim_nf_n(x_n)$.

After all we have a tight sequence $(P_n)$ of probability measures given, hence there is a subsequence again denoted by $(P_n)$ which converges weakly to a measure $P$. Now using the Skorohod Representation Theorem we should establish the following equality:

$$E_P[g(X_N)]=\lim_nE_{P_n}[f_n(X_N)]$$

where $E_p[\cdot]$ denotes the expectation w.r.t the measure $P$, and similaryly for $E_{P_n}[\cdot]$ w.r.t the measure $P_n$. How exactly is in this setting the Skorohod Repesentation Theorem applied? To interchange limit and Expectation, I think we need that $g(x)\le x^p$ and $E_P[S_N^p]<\infty$.

Comment: Your question is actually unclear. What is supposed to be the distribution of $X$ under $P$? under $P_n$?

Comment: Do you take $f_n(x) = 0$ if $x \notin F_n$? In what sense does $\lim F_n = \Bbb R$? is the sequence nested?

Comment: well $F_n=\{\frac{k}{n}:k=0,1,\dots\}$. So it just a grid, which becomes smaller and smaller

Comment: This is weird, because for $E_{P_n}[f_n(X_N)]$ to make sense require that $X_N \in F_n$ holds $P_n$-a.s. If this condition is satisfied, $E_{P_n}[f_n(X_N)] = E_{P_n}[g(X_N)]$...

Comment: @Ju'x I guess that was wrong! The restriction is indeed set to 0 otherwise. I've deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @Ju'x maybe we should continue in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10938/discussion-between-hulik-and-jux

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much time. My feeling is that in order to prove the convergence with Skorohod's lemma in the setting you described, some integrability condition is indeed missing.

Comment: @Ju'x No problem, I'm thankful for any help. I think I found the integrability condition if you can explain why $E_P[g(X)]=E^{'}[g(Z)]$ and same for $f_n$ with $Z_n$ instead of $Z$?

Answer (score 0):

*(I am not sure of the question for now, so this may be useless)*

Skorohod Theorem tells you that you can build on a same probability space $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}',Q')$ a random variable $Z \sim P$ and a sequence of random variables $Z_n \sim P_n$ such that $Z_n \to Z$ with $Q'$-probability 1. In particular,
$$
E_P[g(X)] = E'[g(Z)] \qquad\text{and}\qquad E_{P_n}[f_n(X)] = E'[f_n(Z_n)]
$$

So it is enough to check the convergence $E'[f_n(Z_n)] \to E'[g(Z)]$ on this particular space.

(Hint: use Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem).

Comment: @How exactly should monotone convergence be applied?